# command is run from cmd but not in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sql-loader

I have a `.bat` file in which I insert data from csv to oracle using sqlldr but when I double click .bat file nothing happen.
But when I copy that in cmd and run it executes the data.
I don't know what happen any path mistake or anything.

Batch file

```
P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI>sqlldr upi/upi  DATA=P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI\test.csv CONTROL=Insert.ctl LOG=Insert.log.
```

CTL File

```
OPTIONs(SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA 
INFILE "P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI\test.csv"
INSERT into table DETAIL 
REPLACE
fields terminated by ','
(ID,NAME,ADDRESS,CITY,MOBILE)
```

Comment: by double-clicking, you start the `cmd` window with a homedir of `c:\Windows\system32`, so it probably doesn't find `Insert.ctl` there.

Comment: So what i can do for that can i put Insert.ctl there .when i open cmd it it have address P:\Users\ashique.sheikh

Comment: either provide full path (see Peter's answer) or spend a `cd /d "P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI"`to your batchfile.

Comment: I try both This cd/d "P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI"sqlldr upi/upi DATA=P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI\test.csv CONTROL=P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI\Insert.ctl LOG=Insert.log  and also put a Insert.ctl in P:\Users\ashique.sheikh location but not working

Comment: ahem - `P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI>` is your prompt and shouldn't be in the batchfile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use this line in the bat file:

```
start "" cmd.exe /c sqlldr upi/upi DATA=P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI\test.csv CONTROL=Insert.ctl LOG=Insert.log
```

Some WinodwsXP has a problem as different SET variables when you run cmd.exe and another when you run .bat file. It was antivirus sandbox or something etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the path to the ctl parameter too. I'm  afraid windows searches the path for insert.ctl and it doesn't find it.

Comment: I try both This cd/d "P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI"sqlldr upi/upi DATA=P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI\test.csv CONTROL=P:\Users\ashique.sheikh\VMI\Insert.ctl LOG=Insert.log and also put a Insert.ctl in P:\Users\ashique.sheikh location but not working